# Storing multiple variables in pig

Tags: csv, hadoop, apache-pig

I am extremely new to pig and i am not sure what to google as those results i got didnt really solve my problem.

What i have is now.

```
a = LOAD 'SOME_FILE.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS schema; 
C = FOREACH B GENERATE $0, $1,$2 ; 
STORE C into 'some storage' using PigStorage(';')
```

What i would like to do is run this through a for loop and store them in the same file.

how do i achieve this? Thanks. In other words, i have SOME_FILE.csv, SOME_FILE_1.csv, SOME_FILE_2.csv and so on. But i want to run them through the same FOREACH statement and only run one STORE statement or at least concat the results to the same output.

Sorry if i am unclear in this.

Say instead of `'SOME_FILE_*.csv'`, how do i write it all to the same file? In this case, the number of files i need to process are more than 3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your input files have same schema then :

```
a = LOAD 'SOME_FILE.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS schema;
b = LOAD 'SOME_FILE_1.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS schema;
c = LOAD 'SOME_FILE_2.csv' USING PigStorage(',') AS schema;
```

you can use [**UNION**](https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.7.0/piglatin_ref2.html#UNION) for concatenating your inputs

```
a_b_c = UNION a,b,c; 
C = FOREACH a_b_c GENERATE $0, $1,$2; 
STORE C into 'some storage' using PigStorage(';');
```

Comment: Added a new part to my question

Comment: let say all your csv files are in /your/this/directory/

then data = LOAD '/your/this/directory/*.csv' using PigStorage(',') AS schema; 
will also work, and then do your transformations and storing

Answer (score 0):

you can do in two way

```
 1.use glob function for uploading multiple csv in same directory from hdfs and
```

2. using union

**glob function**
create directory in hdfs and put all SOME_FILE_*.csv in created directory in hdfs

**hadoop dfs -mkdir -p /user/hduser/data**

put csv in created directory in hdfs

**hadoop dfs -put /location_of_file/some_files*.csv /user/hduser/data**

**hadoop dfs -ls /user/hduser/data**

goto grunt shell of apache pig using

**pig -x mapreduce**

**a = load  '/user/hduser/data/{ SOME_FILE, SOME_FILE_1, SOME_FILE_2}.csv' using PigStorage(',') as schema;**

**dump a;**